# How to validate integer values when values is coming as string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass intergers only to a method.But if string values are passing then will get exception.To avoid that i used

```
Int32.tryparse(vatiraleparamter,out int resultparam);
```

But it's showing code violation .we don't use out varieable .please tell me how to avoid this.

Comment: _we don't use out variable_ May I ask you _why_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should declare `integer` variable `resultparam` before passing it to the `TryParse()` method .
Try :

```
    int resultparam;
    if(Int32.TryParse(vatiraleparamter,out resultparam))
    {
      //parsing is successfull.
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is incorrect: `out int resultparam`

You need to pass an existing `int`-variable which will be initialized in [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So the syntax is as following:

```
int resultparam;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(vatiraleparamter, out resultparam);
```

It will be set in `Int32.TryParse` if the string could be parsed successfully. You also get a `bool` which indicates the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use this version of TryParse where you pass the IFrmatProvider as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(v=vs.110).aspx 
This way, the function can recognize decimal separators (which may be commas) from group separators (which also may be commas in some cultures)

The article I mentioned also has a good list of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an existing int variable into the TryParse method. You could also create a method which wraps this functionality, and then flow your code appropriately

```
private static bool StringParsesAsInt(string value)
{
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(value, out result);
}
```

....

```
if StringParsesAsInt(vatiraleparamter) 
{
}
```